# Apple script to activate a window that pops up within Firefox accurately

Tags: firefox, applescript

I have written this piece of code on my MAC OS X 10.10.5 to automate keystrokes on a window that pops up within Firefox.

It does not work reliably and, in many cases, performs the keystrokes on the window in the background. I have tried increasing the delay but it does not seem to be related to timing. The problem, instead, seems to be that the wrong Firefox window is activated.

This is my code. Any ideas on how I can fix it to work reliably.

```
set myBrowser to "/Applications/Firefox.app"
tell application myBrowser
    activate window 2
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab
    delay 2
    keystroke enter
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If Firefox opens up a pop-up window, I believe that window now becomes window 1.   The system events will be sent to that front pop-up window.  Try using this code

```
activate application "Firefox"
tell application "System Events"
    delay 2
    key code 48
    delay 1
    key code 36
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks wch1zpink, I am getting intermittent results. It works sometimes and does not on others. Is there a solution to read something like the window title to check to make sure and then perform the key strokes. Also does stating Tab and Enter make a difference to specifying 48 and 36.

Comment: Try adding a delay after the activating Firefox command. Maybe system events is sending the keystrokes before that Firefox pop-up window is visible.  Unless I'm typing text, I usually always use key codes, Rather than keystrokes.  I just personally find it more reliable.

Comment: I added a delay before the first key code and the script works like a charm for  me every time

Comment: Thanks  wch1zpink 2 . I am trying to find a systematic way of finding out when the pop up is active rather than use a delay but even this only succeeds around 80% of the time

Comment: set windowTitle to ""
tell application "System Events"
 set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
 set frontAppName to name of frontApp
 tell process frontAppName
  tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
   set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
  end tell
 end tell
end tell

tell application "System Events"
 delay 0.5
 keystroke tab
 delay (random number from 0.1 to 0.2)
 keystroke tab end tell

Comment: I think the problem is that delay gets interrupted when called from osascript. It works from Script Editor but not from osascript.